# "Removed tx from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds" on deploy empty contract

Tags: out-of-gas, gas-limit, nonce

First, I know that there is a [similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/why-am-i-getting-removed-tx-from-pool-low-tx-nonce-or-out-of-funds), but maybe we're talking about different problems.

I'm running geth-1.4.3-stable.
My account balance is: `1808.90008114` ether

I want to deploy a contract:

```
contract.new({
  from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
  data: contractData.code.toString(),
  gas: 1000000,
}, function(e, result){
  console.log(e);
  console.log(result);
});
```

Strange thing: there is no error shown, but if I tried to interact with this contract, no data in its storage would've been updated. So I ended up in the logs to see what was going on.

Turns out, I've found this:

```
removed tx (
        TX(bcdfdeae2763eaf0f6fae9d12fb1da3c0d309c0996ca711c87fd91a26a7cf59f)
        Contract: false
        From:     0a27997421b7f332fe79279050f891d9c5e655ba
        To:       [contract creation]
        Nonce:    100
        GasPrice: 20000000000
        GasLimit  1000000
        Value:    0
        Data:     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
        V:        0x1b
        R:        0x7637f8738d36a4b93dd52afb01cd0ee75ddc3ee3cccdceacfd79b58b6faf707
        S:        0x28988f2d86df7f0d89bc9c13d7f671b5b41353a1ecfa149e22df89681f96288
        Hex:      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
) from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds
```

So what now?

Comment: Can you clarify the following: 1) is this on a dev or testnet or the mainnet network? 2) Assuming it is dev, your Nonce of 100 implies that there are 99 transactions before - is this correct? Note that the nonces on testnet start at 2^20 (0x100000) - refer [First Transaction Nonce](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/first-transaction-nonce).

Comment: You may want to use "Script To Find Transactions To/From An Account" in [Common useful JavaScript snippets for geth](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/3750#3750) to check your past transactions.

Comment: I'm on a dev net (id: 4828). About the nonce question, I even cleaned up the nodes and tried again, but no success.

Comment: I'm calling the night. Maybe I'm just too tired. I'll try again tomorrow and give some updates here.

Comment: Move some funds to a newly created account, then try creating your sample (blank) contract specifying the newly created account as the `From:` account.